# ServiceStack + OrmLite Date format issue

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack + OrmLite and I'm having some trouble with OrmLite saving DateTimeOffset objects.

I need to save it into a SQL Server DB with a neutral culture format (for example ISO8601) so when the user changes his culture it won't have any impact on how it's written to the DB because now it's generating `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` errors due to culture conversion issues.

Is there any OrmLite configuration option or something similar to avoid this problem?

Comment: Some code will be helpful. Till then you can check out this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/sYRX5OaPMsk it may help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Date/time types in SQL Server, including `datetime` and `datetimeoffset` are not stored with *any* culture.  They're not stored as strings at all. They are internally stored with a binary representation.

If your class in C# uses a property with a `DateTimeOffset` type, and your table in SQL Server uses a column with a `datetimeoffset` type, then strings (and culture) should never enter the picture.

You might get strings if you manually crafted a SQL string and inlined your values instead of using parameters.  But I doubt an ORM would make this mistake.

Or are you trying to stuff the string representation of a `DateTimeOffset` into a `varchar` field?

Post some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, I don't know why OrmLite seems to be performing some kind of conversion for DateTimeOffset object.

My DB fields are DateTimeOffset(7), the POCO declarations were DateTimeOffset as well and I wasn't manually crafting the SQL query.

I just changed the POCO field to DateTime and now it works like a charm, I thinkt I might open a bug report on github.

However, thankyou for your time !

Comment: It sounds possible there's a bug, so yes - please open an issue with them.

Comment: After further investigation I've found out what's going on, it seems that OrmLite is not building the SQL query properly for DateTimeOffset fields